# a question about entire functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be entire functions on $\mathbb{C}$. If $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then prove there exists constant $c$ such that $f=cg$.

I have no idea... I intend to apply Liuville Theorem but this requires $f/g$ to be an entire function. Is there any version of improved Liuville Theorem?

Comment: The only problem with f/g being entire is if g has a zero where f does not (this clearly can't happen under the hypothesis) or where g has a zero of higher order than f. Can this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ implies that all the zeroes of $g$ are also the zeroes of $f$ with at least that order. It may be possible that $f$ has some other zeroes or same zeroes of higher order than $g$. Cancelling out the common zeroes from $f$ and $g$ we get functions $f_{1}$ and $g_{1}$ and an analytic function $p(z)$ such that $f(z) = p(z)f_{1}(z), g(z) = p(z)g_{1}(z)$ and $g_{1}(z)$ has no zeroes in the finite portion of the complex plane. It follows that the function $h(z) = f_{1}(z)/g_{1}(z)$ is an entire function and $|h(z)| \leq 1$. By Liouville's theorem $h(z) = c$ for all all $z$. Thus we get $f_{1}(z) = cg_{1}(z)$ and hence $f = cg$.